# How can I append Turtle clones to a list without cloning indefinitely?

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I have to write a program in Python using Turtle that reads a list of instructions from a file and draws a Turtle diagram based on the inputs. The possible inputs are forward, left, right, and split. If the input is split, I have to clone all of the turtles in a list and append the new Turtles to the list. All new clones should be turned right by x degrees. The problem is, the turtles clone indefinitely.

```
def navigate(directions):
    turtles = []
    commands = []
    first = turtle.Turtle()
    turtles.append(first)

    turtle.width(10)

    for turt in turtles:
        turt.speed('fastest')
        for step in directions:
            if step[0] == 'forward':
                turt.forward(step[1])
            elif step[0] == 'left':
                turt.left(step[1])
            elif step[0] == 'right':
                turt.right(step[1])
            elif step[0] == 'split':
                new = turt.clone()
                turtles.append(new)
                turt.right(step[1])
```

Directions is a list of tuples where the first value of each tuple is the command (e.g. forward, left, right, or split) and the second is the degree (How far forward to go, how many degrees to turn). But the turtle continue to clone forever. How can I adjust this code so that it only clones a given number of times? Here is my sample input file:

```
forward 50
left 20
split 40
forward 50
left 20
split 40
forward 50
left 20
split 40
forward 50
left 20
split 40
forward 50
left 20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you have a logic error. Your outer loop iterates over the turtles, and then inside the loop, it processes *all* the steps for each turtle separately. This is incorrect; even if it worked, it would apply instructions from *before* the split to turtles created after it. (That would effectively apply those preceding instructions twice to the same turtle, as well as execute the split *again*.) You need to process a single step at a time on all turtles. So the loop needs to be over the directions, not the turtles:

```
for step in directions:
    # Process the step
```

Now that we have the loops swapped, a solution becomes more obvious. We can check the step and have special handling for the `'split'` case:

```
for step in directions:
    if step[0] == 'split':
        # Clone all the turtles here
    else:
        for turt in turtles:
            if step[0] == 'forward':
                turt.forward(step[1])
            elif step[0] == 'left':
            ...
```

I chose to use a single loop for the movement cases, but it would be equally valid to have a loop for each case if you prefer.

We still have the issue of creating the clones and adding them to the list. You already saw this **won't** work:

```
for turt in turtles:
    turtles.append(turt.clone())
```

So we need to store all these new clones without modifying the list we're looping over. We can do that with a temporary list:

```
turtle_clones = []
for turt in turtles:
    turtle_clones.append(turt.clone())
```

And then we just need to put `turtle_clones` onto the end of `turtles`. I'll leave combining the two lists as an exercise for you.

#### Bonus Material

Here are some suggestions to make your code cleaner:

1. Use unpacking so you don't have to have indexes everywhere.

   You actually don't need to access the two pieces of data in `step` using an index. You can use unpacking to put each element in its own variable:

   ```
   for action, value in directions:
       if action == 'split':
           ...
       else:
           ...
               turt.forward(value)
   ```

   This makes you code much simpler and easy to read, although you can probably think of a better name for `value`.
2. You actually don't have to use an explicit temporary list and `for` loop to make the clones. You can use a list comprehension:

   ```
   turtle_clones = [t.clone() for t in turtles]
   ```

   Again, much simpler and easy to read.
3. The `first` variable appears unnecessary. You can initialize the list containing the first turtle directly:

   ```
   turtles = [turtle.Turtle()]
   ```

Comment: Thank you!! Got it working. I know that the nesting of the loops was part of the problem but wasn't sure how to fix it. You gave me everything I needed.

Comment: @nalydttirrem Identifying the proper abstractions is easily the most difficult part of programming, but you'll get better at it over time. =) Take this experience as a lesson: when things aren't really falling into place, that's often an indication that the way you're modeling your data or your logic doesn't suit your needs very well.